# How to use spatie permission middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am using Laravel 8 and Spatie Role and Permission. Permission for each action working fine. But if i assign **delete action** permission to sub admin but I hit  **create action** directly from URL middlware can not stop action as user have not create permission.

```
 public function __construct(CustomerInterface $customerInterface)
{
    $this->customerInterface = $customerInterface;
    $this->middleware(['permission:create_customer|delete_customer|edit_customer|chnage_customer_status']);
}
```

I am using above middleware in constructor. How can i Solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from the [documentation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v4/basic-usage/middleware), when you use the `permission` middleware with multiple permissions, it will let the request proceed if **at least** one permission checks out.

What you need is method-based authorization and for that, Laravel uses [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies) which by default lets you write separate authorization for common methods. (index, store, update, show, etc)

Let's say you let a user use the `store` method only if they have the `create_customer` permission, your policy will look something like this:

```php
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->can('create_customer');
    }
```

Then in your controller, you put the `authorizeResource` function which associates the default policy methods with your default resource controller methods:

```php
    public function __construct(CustomerInterface $customerInterface)
    {
        $this->customerInterface = $customerInterface;
        $this->authorizeResource(Customer::class); // assuming your model name is Customer
    }
```

alternatively, you can write your own custom policy methods and use them via the `$this->authorize` method which is documented further [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers).

Answer (score 0):

In Your controller use

```
public function __construct(MembershipService $membershipService)
{
    $this->membershipService = $membershipService;
    $this->middleware(['permission:can_view_memberships']);
}
```